# Can indexedDB be overused in attempting to constantly capture the current state?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm sure this is a rather novice question but I hadn't thought much about it while studying indexedDB and, now that I have it working well in a semi-complex single page app with a tabbed layout, I started thinking about how much work it is for the machine to write to the database and when to write versus holding data in RAM.

If an app involves collecting and editing a fair amount of user input, can indexedDB be overused in attempting to constantly capture the current state, such that it taxes the machine; and would it be better to just add a 'Save' button to save the state and minimize the number of database operations?

In this app, some data items aren't written until the user navigates away from a tab but other data, like text inputs, are written on each change event. I've been building an undo/redo chain in a separate object store and writing to it after each new element is added/deleted/moved or text edited.  Would it be better to hold more of the data in RAM until a more significant event takes place?

I haven't experienced any issues while testing and building, but thought it might be prudent to ask about this since this is an area about which I know very little.

Thank you.

---

I've been working with this for the past few months and think that although indexedDB is very fast there are a couple items to keep in mind. One, of course, is to not alter the DOM until the database operation has completed unless you have a DOM rollback method in place. Also, when watching RAM usage and garbage collection, and you think about how many times a `get/put` operation takes up some RAM and holds it until the GC cycle runs, it can be more efficient to just hold some of that data in RAM and use a `put` operation only and never need to temporarily hold the result of a `get` in RAM. It may sound a bit strange but when you start watching memory usage and thinking about the steps involved, especially when the state is very frequently captured in a piece-meal manner, these can become important considerations.  Perhaps not, if you just assume everyone has a lot of RAM these days and the GC will quickly release the memory; but, if you're trying to do things "right" just because you want to be as efficient as possible whether you can get by or not without doing so, then these become important.  Also, in my case, this is a tool that the user may use for a couple of hours in a single session and all of that could add up to a slow browser.